# How many times can I attempt to guess the pin code of the restrictions settings on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, password, settings

I want to change some settings related to restrictions on my iPad but I don't remember the code I used to lock changes to restrictions. I have a few common variations to try, I'm certain it is one of them, but I noticed that the device counts the attempts I've already made.

Will I be blocked from further attempts at some point or is just an informative counter?

Comment: Try to remember important times, dates, and others things in your life before you reach the 10th attempt, if you set it to erase everything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are talking about Parental Control type of restrictions on the iPad, I believe that to be entirely iOS software level. You have 6 attempts before it locks you out for a minute. It then increases the locked-out time after further failed attempts. Since you have two failed attempts, it should let you have four more without consequence, which, if one goes through, all is well, if not, you will be locked out, before you can do a 7th attempt for 1 minute - to start with.

If you fail the 7th time, it will increase the time to 5 minutes.
The eight time increases it to 15 minutes.
And if you fail the ninth time, the timer increases to sixty minutes and will be that amount until you enter the right one.

Comment: Source? I got up to 5 attempts before getting spooked and it hasn't locked me out. (I think I've remembered the passcode now, but I *really* don't want to risk it locking up. I was hoping SE had the correct answer.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, Apple appears not to mention anything conclusive about it. You bring up a good point - thank you - I will edit my answer as I just tested it. I suppose it is possible they have changed something in iOS 6? And - you're right, as you know, SE *is* the place for the correct answer. :)

Comment: +1 for science! Internet hearsay says everything from 3 to 20 attempts before doom befalls your data, so empirical research is very helpful. (And brave!)

Comment: I'm at 9 tries and can't try again for an hour.

Comment: If you have it set to do so, iOS will erase the entire contents after 10 failed attempts. I have my iPhone set to do this (in case it's ever lost and someone tries to break in). So be careful with that 10th try; it may erase everything if you get it wrong.